# UITableView lags with images

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My problem is when I scroll down my UITableView, it looks too laggy. The images grab from Facebook.

My code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UserCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        let user = users[indexPath.row] as User //2
        
        if let nameLabel = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel { //3
            nameLabel.text = user.name
        }
        
        if let dateCreatedLabel = cell.viewWithTag(101) as? UILabel {
        dateCreatedLabel.text = user.distance
        }
        
        if let profilePictureView = cell.viewWithTag(103) as? UIImageView {
            if let url = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/\(user.profilePhoto)/picture?type=large") {
                if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
                    profilePictureView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
                    profilePictureView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

How can I make it smooth?

Comment: Look for questions and answers about loading images in background.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/swift-loading-image-from-url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already found the answer. Use `Haneke` instead `NSData`.

```
import Haneke

/* .. */

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UserCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        let user = users[indexPath.row] as User //2

        if let nameLabel = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel { //3
            nameLabel.text = user.name
        }

        if let dateCreatedLabel = cell.viewWithTag(101) as? UILabel {
        dateCreatedLabel.text = user.distance
        }

        if let profilePictureView = cell.viewWithTag(103) as? UIImageView {
            if let url = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/\(user.profilePhoto)/picture?type=large") {
                    profilePictureView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
                    profilePictureView.hnk_setImageFromURL(url!)

            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

OMG, never do like this not only in scrolling controls, but in general UI also:

> data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)

Thats why you table lags, and you lucky enougth with fast internet. If you connection will be slow, you app will hang, may be forever. ALWAYS do network asyncronously!

Also, when you make you network async, your tableView will still lag here:

> UIImage(data: data)

And even here if you have many controls in your cell:

> cell.viewWithTag(101)

So, use some library to download images, this is surprisingly not so easy task as it seems to be, you will not do it right yourself according to you experience (as I can see it).

Make separate class for you cell and use IB to connect outlets.

Try AFNetworking, it has category for UIImageView to download images.

Comment: So how i can fix this problem?

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin see my updated answer, you code with swift, not so many libraries for it now I think (I code with objective-c and there are couple of them, try to adopt AFNetworking f.e.)

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin Yes, this is from author of AFNetworking, so it's exactly what you need.